# rails database query, html drop down, interaction 1:n relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, relationship

Good Evening Guys,

I have generated four scaffolds Person, Trainer, Sportsman and Index.

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :alter, :name
end

class Sportler < Person
   belongs_to :trainer
end

class Trainer < Person
  has_many :sportler
end
```

Then I have created one Form: views/index/index.html.erb

```
<table>
  <tr>
      <td>Trainer</td>
      <td>
        trainers = Trainer.find(:all)


        <% @trainers.each do |trainer| %>

          puts "print Results in <select> as Options"
          <select name="trainer">
              </option>Max Musterman</option>
          </select>

        <% end %>

      </td>

      <td>
        <%= link_to 'Neuer Trainer', new_trainer_path %>
      </td>

    <tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sportler</td>
      <td>
<!--
 <% @sportlers.each do |sportler| %>
       <select name="sportler">
       </select>
 <% end %>
-->
      </td>
      <td>
        <%= link_to 'Neuer Sportler', new_sportler_path %>
      </td>
    <tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td><input type="button" name="trSpAdd" value="Hinzufügen"></td>
    <tr>


</table>
```

**Now I want to add the Trainer and Sportman to the DropDown's.**
**One Trainer can have 1 or more Sportman. One Sportsman can have 1 Trainer. This have to be considered when using the form.
How can i solve this.**

My beginning is this, it doesnet query the Trainer rows and put it into the drop down:

```
    trainers = Trainer.find(:all)


    <% @trainers.each do |trainer| %>

      puts "print Results in <select> as Options"
      <select name="trainer">
          </option>Max Musterman</option>
      </select>

    <% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the select_tag from the FormTagHelper, something like this:

```
select_tag "trainer", options_from_collection_for_select(@trainers, "id", "name")
```

Comment: thanks. Where should i add this code?  I founded this page http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html i try the first one, i added the code in the view , nothing happens                   select("post", "trainer", Post::CATEGORIES, {:include_blank => true})

Comment: For what stands the :post, i have several views, this code is not in the trainer view

Comment: ah ok i found your code in the tutorial. I added this in my view   <% select_tag "trainer", options_from_collection_for_select(@trainers, "id", "name") %>
and i get this error undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass

Comment: this code goes: <%= collection_select(:trainer, :trainer_id, Trainer.all, :id, :name) %>

Comment: Sorry, I copied your use of `@trainers` assuming it was made available from within the controller.  I see you are actually doing trainers = Trainer.find(:all), in which case you would replace `@trainers` with trainers (no @).  Also the statement should be in <% %>.  But I would suggest that you move the call to Trainer.find(:all) to your controller.